# Why is my windows 8.1 starting fast but restarting very slow?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, reboot

I've just formatted my Lenovo G510 pc and reboot time is about 3 minutes.
 - While rebooting, to the lenovo screen it takes 10,20 seconds,
 - After the black screen it takes about 2 minutes,
and finally user login screen takes 10,20 seconds.
 - When fully opened i opened the task manager and the service host disk usage was  at %100 for about 2 , 3 minutes.

What is the problem ? (I've installed all updates.)

Comment: capture a boot trace if you want to see the details of the slowness: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `Fast Startup` where Windows never completely shuts down *unless* you restart. Rather, it will do a hybrid shutdown, where it will partially shut down, partially hibernate.

This method means it unloads the `User Space` and hibernates the `System Space` including the drivers, which means on a full start (or reboot) Windows has to load all the drivers, where as with Fast Boot it only restores the `System Space` rather than loading it.

Comment: I know restart must take longer than startup but isn't this so long ?

Comment: @NurullahMacun a full reboot taking ~5 minutes isn't anything unusual. Windows will still be loading the last parts of the system and/or userspace(s)

Comment: @NurullahMacun if this answer helped you, mind marking it as the answer?